# Where can i find unix/linux tool for fuzzing for kill-switches?

Tags: hardware, linux, fuzzing, networking

I'm looking for linux/unix open-source tools for fuzzing ethernet card for kill-switch packets.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing

I can imagine how it would be long to brute full of range on physical level.

That is why, i'm looking for ready to go heuristic tool and special ethernet card for this task.

Comment: Looks like this question would be better asked at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is pure RE. Why do you think security is better?

Comment: What is it that you're reverse engineering?

Comment: There is an older RE SE question about fuzzing that might be of some help. Have you seen http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/where-can-i-learn-more-about-black-box-fuzzing-of-small-embedded-systems ?

It does not address ethernet cards or kill-switch packets specifically, but you might be able to adapt the sully or Peach Fuzzer tools referenced in the question to your own purposes. (I do not have experience with either tool.)